# ember 1.7.1 not working with handlebars 2.0.0

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm currently working on a new ember project after a smooth and successful one page angularjs application.

So I prepared my work folder, and ironically the second I start using emberjs i.e as soon as I reference the script tag it throws up an error saying *handlebars is not defined*.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?
I'm using emberjs v.1.7.1 add handlebars 2.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember works with a one-off version of handlebars, the currently supported version is 1.3.  It's available from the front page of http://emberjs.com/

Comment: @Dhaulagiri I haven't really written any emberjs or handlebars code yet it just won't work.

Comment: I changed it from 2.0.0 to 1.3.0 and it works now really made my day thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ember support for Handlebars 2.x is planned from Ember version 1.9 as stated on ember.js blog.

> Since the release of Ember 1.0.0, Ember has required Handlebars 1.x.
>   As each new version of Handlebars has been released we have needed to
>   update our version requirement to allow the latest and greatest.
>   Thankfully, throughout this process we have been able to maintain
>   backwards compatibility with all versions of Handlebars since 1.0.0.
>
> Unfortunately, Ember will not be able to maintain backwards
>   compatibility to 1.x versions of Handlebars while supporting 2.0. In
>   Ember 1.9.0 (which will be released to beta on October 24th and stable
>   on December 5th) support for Handlebars 1.x will be removed, and
>   support for Handlebars 2.0 introduced.